# How to Create a Firestore Subcollection and Add to It?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to create a function that adds inputted content to a Firestore collection document then creates a subcollection for that document, takes the rest of the content and puts it into a document in that subcollection. However, I've been running into an issue where I can add to a collection but not then create and add to the subcollection. Is there any way to fix this? My code is below.

```
document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
var storyTitle = document.getElementById("storyTitle").value;
  var chapterTitle = tinymce.get("writeTitle").getContent();
  var chapterContent = tinymce.get("chapterContent").getContent();
  const db = firebase.firestore();
              
  
  addStory(storyTitle,chapterTitle,chapterContent);
  
});
    
function addStory(story,chapter,theContent) {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const sub = db.collection("Stories").doc(story).collection("Chapters");
  //const docRef = db.collection("Stories").doc(storyTitle);
  document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = story + ", " + chapter + ", " + theContent;

db.collection("Stories").doc(story).set({
    title: story
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});

db.collection("Stories").document(story).collection("Chapters").add({
    title: chapter,
    content: theContent
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what I think you should do:

```
  const storiesRef = db.collection('Stories').doc(story).get();
  const chapterRef = storiesRef.collection('Chapters').doc();
```

You can make the entire function asynchronous, that way you can await setting/updating each collection with it's respective values like so:

```
 await storiesRef.set({
   title: story
 });

 await chapterRef.set({
   title: chapter,
   content: theContent
 });
```

Meanwhile you can take a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model. The docs fully explains how to create subcollections.

I do hope this helps.

Comment: Here's the function now but it doesn't work.

async function addStory(story,chapter,theContent) {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = "Story Title: " + story;
  const storiesRef = db.collection('Stories').doc(story).get();
  const chapterRef = storiesRef.collection('Chapters').doc();


await storiesRef.set({
   title: story
});

await chapterRef.set({
   title: chapter,
   content: theContent
});

}

Comment: This looks fine though. If you are not able to write to store, double check to make sure you have read/write privileges

Comment: Did you check the permissions? Were they properly set?